# Is there a way to remove lines being added to markdown file from django textarea?

Tags: django, markdown, textarea

When creating an entry such as

```
# Title
This is an entry
```

The following file is created

```
# Title

This is an entry
```

When I update this file, more spaces are added. I want the spaces to be removed and only show when the user inputs spaces. The code snippets are not the complete files but should provide the relevant code that connects everything together.

**views.py**

```
class NewEntryForm(forms.Form):
  title = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
  entry = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))

def create(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        print(request.POST.get('entry'))
        form = NewEntryForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            title = form.cleaned_data["title"].strip()
            if util.get_entry(title):
                return render(request, "encyclopedia/create.html", {
                    "form": form,
                    "exists": True,
                    "title": title
                })
            else:
                entry = form.cleaned_data["entry"]
                print(entry)
                util.save_entry(title, entry)
                return redirect("entry", title=title)
        else:
            return render(request, "encyclopedia/create.html", {
                "form": form,
                "exists": False
            })
    return render(request, "encyclopedia/create.html", {
        "form": NewEntryForm(),
        "exists": False
    })
```

**create.html**

```
{% block body %}
  <h2>New Entry</h2>
  <form class="entry-form" action="{% url 'create' %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    {% if exists %}
      <p class="alert alert-danger">Entry '{{ title }}' already exists.</p>
    {% endif %}
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mt-3">
  </form>
{% endblock %}
```

**utils.py**

```
def save_entry(title, content):
    """
    Saves an encyclopedia entry, given its title and Markdown
    content. If an existing entry with the same title already exists,
    it is replaced.
    """
    filename = f"entries/{title}.md"
    if default_storage.exists(filename):
        default_storage.delete(filename)
    default_storage.save(filename, ContentFile(content))
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a better answer.

[Newlines in textarea are doubled in number when saved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63004501/newlines-in-textarea-are-doubled-in-number-when-saved)